# How to execute one module using conditionals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

```
module "s3_bucket" {source = "./module/s3_bucket"}
module "s3_bucket_2" {source = "./module/s3_bucket_2"}
```

These are my two modules which I am calling in the main.tf file, but I want to use some conditions so that I can call any one module which I want at any point of time and only that module gets executed at that time, so is their any way to do that?

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt understand quite your question but i guess what you want or at least would be helpfull to answer your question is the following.

You can create a variable in variables.tf called for example create and then pass it to a module.

```
# Set a variable to know if the resources inside the module should be created

module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "./module/s3_bucket"
  create = var.create
}

# For every resource inside use the count to create or not each resource
resource "resource_type" "resource_name" {
 count = var.create ? 1 : 0

 ... other resource attributes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try this out.